# What is the best way to type variables in a custom Writable type?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm defining a custom writable type and currently I have something like this:

```
public static class MyType implements Writable {
  private int value1;
  private String value2;

  // ... override code etc 
}
```

Should I be using ints and Strings or should these make use of intWritable and Text? The examples I've seen tend to use the method I've employed, but it seems like you could be more efficient using the Writable types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use int, string etc. That is perfectly fine. and as you are implementing Writable you will need to override `readFields(DataInput in)` and  `write(DataOutput out)` method. You will need to read write varibles in same order. That is where serialisation take place. And you don't need to take pain to make variables of writable type.

Answer (score 1):

That is perfectly fine, since you are doing the serialization by overriding read and write. You can write primitives like `ints` using `readInt()` or `writeInt()` and so forth with other primitives or Strings.

`Text` and `LongWritables` for example are mainly used to have some built-in types that can be used. If you need to compose objects you are perfectly fine with using primitives, `Text` or `LongWritable` are nothing else than a kind of serializable wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

I tend to compose the Writables like Text, because there are some heavy optimizations for I/O that have been done in those classes.  However, the best bet is to try it both ways and see which one performs better.

Comment: In fact `LongWritable` just does a `out.writeLong()` and `Text` just writes the byte array that is forming the string. So there is no extra optimization done within the classes. You just have additional object allocation overhead when using them instead of primitives.

Comment: OK, what about custom WritableComparable< T > then.  Surely nobody wants to go through the trouble of re-implementing the RawComparable in Text, say; better to just use it.

Comment: If you use `WritableComparable` then you can simply compare the strings by their compareTo function. If you have the need to implement your own `RawComparator`, then you can bypass an existing implementation or write your own. Text compares only the byte array, nothing special to implement.